# Has anyone use this User Defined Form module from Silverstripe?

Tags: php, silverstripe

It's a long short question since Silverstripe is still pretty new in the CMS market as compared to others...

As the subject heading states,  has anyone played with silverstripe and use one of these User defined form module as part of its core API?

I'm wonder has anyone attempted to make successful modifications module to suit their own custom requirements?

What I find it challenging about this is there's lack of code samples or documentation that would allow to appreciate how User Defined form works and how I can modify and manipulate its configuration settings to what I want to achieve?

Is there anybody out there who can lend a helping hand on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the module. What modifications are you hoping to make exactly? You can easily decorate or subclass parts of a module to add custom functionality without modifying the core code.

Here's some documentation that could give you some insight into the Decorator option.

http://doc.silverstripe.org/sapphire/en/reference/dataobjectdecorator

But yeah, let us know what you are trying to do and I should be able to give you more detailed suggestions :)

Given your additional info below -

It might not be worth using UDF for this, the work required would not be much more or less than the more straight forward option to create a frontend form from scratch. http://doc.silverstripe.org/sapphire/en/topics/forms

But if you wanted to go ahead with UDF you would need to do something like -

1) extend UserDefinedForm eg. CustomUserDefinedForm extends UserDefinedForm to have an extra field/dbfield where you could select the name of the DataObject to map to.

2) Decorate EditableFormField to have an extra field that maps it to the appropriate field of the DataObject.

3) extend UserDefinedForm_Controller eg. CustomUserDefinedForm_Controller extends UserDefinedForm_Controller and override the 'process' method. This is where the form is saved and the email is sent. You would need to add code to loop over the fields and save them to the dataobject specified on the form.

Comment: Thanks for your input.  This is great.  I posted a similar question at Silverstripe forum today, hoping to find some decent help in a reasonable size community of Silverstripe 'junkies'.  No one replied over there.. then I gave Stackoverflow a go, knowing the response rate would be slim to none (at best) - until now! Anyway, I digress - I'm trying to modify UDF's module so in an given form, all of its input fields are mapped to datafields of a Dataobject.  The form is data-bound by table with its respective fields so it can be saved into the table.  What do you think?

Comment: Thanks for that.  I'll have a look at it when I have free time.  You've been a great help!  Cheers!